# Sql Server to Ms Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I am moving my database from SQL Server to MS Access for portability feature and I am stuck in the *Varbinary* field type of SQL Server. What should I choose in MS Access database?

```
Sql Server                 MsAccess
-----------------------------------
Images                     OLEObjects
Varbinary                  what should i choose?
```

I am using SQL Server 2005, with Visual Studio 2010 and the Access database is for 2010 as well.

Comment: I tried 4 hours in linking sql server with data source but it failed. So i thought to make it manually. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good idea to store images and blob objects in an Access database.  While it's technically feasible to use an OLE Object to do so, it doesn't take to many images/blobs to be stored before seeing Access to start crawling like a turtle.  Most people will choose to keep these binary objects outside of the database and to store only the filenames inside the Access database.

Comment: The Image enteries will be done one time, Its like entering the employees profile, after that there will be no more image enteries.

Comment: You should also take a look at the new Attachments data type that is available with Access 2010; see http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/attach-files-and-graphics-to-the-records-in-your-database-HA010341505.aspx

Comment: If you do not have Access 2010, blobs for images are not quite so bad: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/103257

Answer (score 1):

The alternative of `VarBinary` is `OLE Object`.

For more detail please [see this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssma/archive/2011/03/06/access-to-sql-server-migration-understanding-data-type-conversions.aspx).